# How do include a property at runtime in a spring context?

Tags: java, spring

How do I add properties at runtime and use them to populate placeholders in my context files?

First, a little background: I have a batch data loader which loads a database. I have a requirement that the database password is not stored on disk for this program, so I allow the user to enter it interactively. 
I am using hibernate, and my datasource is configured in a context file, with the actual parameters in another properties file.

Some attributes of what I'm looking for

- The property is available only at runtime (user entered password)
- It can be provided before the context loads
- It doesn't need to dynamically change
- Other related properties are still loaded via a normal properties file

**db.xml:**

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${hibernate.connection.driver_class}" />
    <property name="url" value="${hibernate.connection.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${hibernate.connection.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${hibernate.connection.password}" />
    and so on...
</bean>
```

**database.properties:**

```
hibernate.connection.username=Username
### hibernate.connection.password= #don't want the password stored
hibernate.connection.url=<the url>
hibernate.connection.driver_class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

And my main **context.xml:**

```
<import resource="classpath:db.xml" />
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations" value="classpath:database.properties" />
</bean>
plus more...
```

What I want to do is add a new property (`hibernate.connection.password`) to the context before refreshing it at runtime so that the corresponding value is replaced in `db.xml`.

My current attempt looks like this

```
Properties prop = new Properties();             
prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", thePassword);
PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
ppc.setProperties(prop);

ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"my-context.xml"}, false); // Don't refresh after loading
ctx.addBeanFactoryPostProcessor(ppc);
ctx.refresh();
```

I must be doing something wrong, however, since I get an exception that tells me the properties from my `database.properties` file are not being used.

```
2016-03-14 14:58:41 WARN  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext:546 - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [db.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'hibernate.connection.driver_class' in string value "${hibernate.connection.driver_class}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'hibernate.connection.driver_class' in string value "${hibernate.connection.driver_class}"
```

To be sure my setup for the database.properties file is correct, if I remove the call to `ctx.addBeanFactoryPostProcessor(ppc)`, I instead get an exception complaining about the missing password

```
2016-03-14 16:52:10 WARN  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext:546 - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [db.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'hibernate.connection.password' in string value "${hibernate.connection.password}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'hibernate.connection.password' in string value "${hibernate.connection.password}"
Error: Invalid bean definition with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [db.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'hibernate.connection.password' in string value "${hibernate.connection.password}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'hibernate.connection.password' in string value "${hibernate.connection.password}"
```

And if the password is present in the properties file, everything works fine.

*My question then is how do I cause both the database.properties and the runtime-defined property to post-process my context files?*

**Edit**

One solution I have found is to manually load the properties file into the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.

```
ppc.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("database.properties"));
```

This works, however the property set programmatically will be overridden by any matching property in the properties file, which makes it feel like a workaround. Also, I still don't understand why both PropertyPlaceholderConfigurers don't get used (the one defined in the context file and the one defined in java)

Comment: what do you mean by run time,during application start up or after ?

Comment: Yes, around application startup

Comment: is this web application?

Comment: It's a batch data loader, so, no.

Answer (score 1):

In order for Spring to read the properties from `database.properties` you'll have to define a bean of Properties Placeholder like below:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>database.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Then you can use it in your `dataSource` bean as follows:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${hibernate.connection.driver_class}" />
    <property name="url" value="${hibernate.connection.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${hibernate.connection.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${hibernate.connection.password}" />
    and so on...
</bean>
```

If you want to pass the password at run-time then you can pass it as an argument as follows:

```
-Dhibernate.connection.password=<password>
```

Comment: Ok, maybe I edited my reply too tightly. I do already have a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in my context file. I'll edit that into my question

Comment: @benf It might be because later on you are overwriting the definition by doing `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();` and `ctx.addBeanFactoryPostProcessor(ppc);`.

Comment: Passing it on the CLI would be convenient, but the desire is that it doesn't appear in the /proc/<pid>/cmdline string either.

Comment: Yes, that is what I suspect is happening. What I am trying to find out is how to merge instead of overwrite

Comment: @benf In our project we pass an encrypted string as argument and perform the decryption in code before using it. I'm not sure if it would be feasible but you can also look at Kerberos where you can pass the login credentials in form of a `keyTab` file.